# How to determine the duration of a audio file in Node or Express?

Tags: node.js, audio, express, duration, multer

I am uploading an audio file from a form to the server using the module `multer` with Express. I would need to know the duration of the track somehow. Is that possible, and if yes, how?

Answer (score -5):

You can get audio's duration before it is being uploaded. See the examples below.

Using jQuery, here's a [solution](https://jsfiddle.net/derickbailey/s4P2v/) (where a lib is needed)

```
$("#audio").on("canplaythrough", function(e){
var seconds = e.currentTarget.duration;
var duration = moment.duration(seconds, "seconds");

var time = "";
var hours = duration.hours();
if (hours > 0) { time = hours + ":" ; }

time = time + duration.minutes() + ":" + duration.seconds();
$("#duration").text(time);

URL.revokeObjectURL(objectUrl);
});
```

Or, with plain Javascript, another [solution](http://coursesweb.net/javascript/duration-audio-video-file-before-upload_cs)

```
var f_duration =0;  //store duration
document.getElementById('audio').addEventListener('canplaythrough', function(e){
  //add duration in the input field #f_du
  f_duration = Math.round(e.currentTarget.duration);
  document.getElementById('f_du').value = f_duration;
  URL.revokeObjectURL(obUrl);
});
```

Or you can get audio duration by HTML5 audio API.

See this: [W3Schools Example](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_audio_duration.asp) and [HTML AUDIO DOM OBJECT](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_audio.asp)

```
document.getElementById("myAudio").duration
```

Comment: This answer assumes you're working with a browser which may not be the case with Node.

Comment: might not be safe to calculate this duration on the browser